# An army of hackers put America's power grid in its sights - meaning of in its sights

Tags: meaning, usage

Source: http://gizmodo.com/you-just-missed-a-massive-destructive-fake-cyberatta-1465317346

> What would happen if an army of hackers put America's power grid **in its sights** and pulled the trigger? How fast would the country descend into darkness? Would there be anarchy in the streets? Would people die? According to a war game carried out across the country this week, the answer is not necessarily good news.

I can't figure out the meaning of **in its sights** in this sentence.

Comment: http://monosnap.com/image/tCIoCgXoIhe8om4eKFhKDhPU0HnZVp.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Sights](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/sights) are the parts of a weapon - for instance, a gun - that lets you aim it more accurately.

This is a metaphor: to *put something in your sights* is to aim at it, and so you could congruently phrase it instead:

> What would happen if an army of hackers *aimed at* America's power grid...

Answer (score 4):

She's got you in her sights:

[image]

As jimsug's answer says, the sights are a part of a weapon which help you to aim it.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to an **intense focus**, and as mentioned above, through the scope of a weapon. It implies that the entire problem is being viewed and processed in great detail. There is an assumption that a solution or more information will be provided and the person who is focusing is in a position of power to control the situation.

There is a sense of urgency in the saying.

Answer (score 1):

in its sight, as for that sentence, means as their target, as far as i know. It fits quite nicely too, "What would happen if an army of hackers put America's power grid as their target and pulled the trigger"